# ITK/SimpleITK DICOM Series Loaded in wrong order / slice spacing incorrect

Tags: python, dicom, imaging, itk

The problem occurs with a number of the datasets, but we particularly noticed it with [Soft-tissue-Sarcoma](https://wiki.cancerimagingarchive.net/display/Public/Soft-tissue-Sarcoma) in the dicoms in

```
STS_004/1.3.6.1.4.1.14519.5.2.1.5168.1900.124239320067253523699285035604/1.3.6.1.4.1.14519.5.2.1.5168.1900.952127023780097934747932279670
```

The spacing is read as 30 instead of 2.9 and the 3D image has brain slices between two lung slices

Comment: VTK was tagged because there appeared to be a similar issue [here](http://public.kitware.com/pipermail/vtkusers/2008-December/049808.html)

Answer (score 3):

Basically if you read the dicoms using SimpleITK.ReadImage or VTK the tool loads the files in the same order your list is in (usually alphabetical order). The mapping between the slices and the files are not in alphabetical order and are instead in a random order. This causes the Slice Spacing (a tag that is missing in these data) to be computed incorrectly since it is the difference in position between file 0 and 1. It also causes brain slices to turn up between two lung slices and other strange artifacts.

The solution is to presort the files using the `GetGDCMSeriesFileNames` function.

```
# noinspection PyPep8Naming
import SimpleITK as sitk

def safe_sitk_read(img_list, *args, **kwargs):
    dir_name = os.path.dirname(img_list[0]) 
    s_img_list = sitk.ImageSeriesReader().GetGDCMSeriesFileNames(dir_name)
    return sitk.ReadImage(s_img_list, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I believe GDCMImageIO is doing the right thing. Also `GetOrigin` is not `Slice Location` AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

So here is what I tried on my side:

```
$ gdcm2vtk --lower-left --ipp-sort STS_004/1.3.6.1.4.1.14519.5.2.1.5168.1900.124239320067253523699285035604/1.3.6.1.4.1.14519.5.2.1.5168.1900.952127023780097934747932279670 /tmp/kmader.mha
```

And then I check the output file with:

```
$ head -13 /tmp/kmader.mha 
ObjectType = Image
NDims = 3
BinaryData = True
BinaryDataByteOrderMSB = False
CompressedData = False
TransformMatrix = 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
Offset = -250 -250 -5
CenterOfRotation = 0 0 0
ElementSpacing = 0.976562 0.976562 3.3
DimSize = 512 512 311
AnatomicalOrientation = ???
ElementType = MET_SHORT
ElementDataFile = LOCAL
```

Indeed you are right, GDCM computes the Z-Spacing as being 3.3 while it should really be 3.27 in this case. Please report a bug upstream.

---

Fixed in current git repository:

- https://github.com/malaterre/GDCM/commit/36b7fbce6d2bd146cfa7541a175c8f6519da7dba

Comment: Thanks, I assume unfortunately that it could still be a very long time before the python packages reflect the updates to GDCM so little hacks will be required in the meantime

Comment: @kmader `GetOrigin` returns an index in 3D space. You seems to be taking the 1st coordinate. This wont work if you use another direction for acquisition. Also `Slice Location` is a vendor specific ordering that is optional (potentially unrelated to 3D space).

Comment: is there a better solution now using SimpleITK inside of python? or do I need to manually pull the latest master branch, compile gdcm2vtk, execute it on the list, and then read the MHA in?

Comment: I would use one of the example from SimpleITK directly. eg https://itk.org/SimpleITKDoxygen/html/DicomSeriesReader_8py-example.html